# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

getting this error in my local server. but this code is running in online
where its not showing any error. now what can i do? error show empty(count($leadcount)) this condition

```
if(empty(count($leadcount))){
                                    if(!empty($leadManagements)){
                                        $LeadSend = $this->LeadSend->newEntity();
                                        $inqData['requirement_id'] = $Requirements->id;
                                        $inqData['lead_management_id'] = $leadManagements->id;
                                        $inqData['send_date'] = Time::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', date('Y-m-d'));
                                        $inqData['lead_type'] = 'booking';
                                        $inqData['is_active'] = 1;
                                        $inqData['is_delete'] = 1;
                                        $LeadSend = $this->LeadSend->patchEntity($LeadSend, $inqData);
                                        if($this->LeadSend->save($LeadSend)){
                                            $expression = new QueryExpression('booking_lead_count = booking_lead_count + 1');
                                            $expression2 = new QueryExpression('lead_sent_count = lead_sent_count + 1');
                                            $this->LeadManagements->updateAll([$expression,$expression2], ['id' => $leadManagements->id]);
                                            //lead_type send_date
                                            $this->notificationBuyer($this->request->data);
                                            $this->notificationSeller($this->request->data);
                                        }

                                    }

                                } else {
                                    /// allready send inquery 
                                }
```

Comment: Whenever you encounter problem with different servers, compare your setups, figure out the difference, and these details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Surely it should simply be either `if(empty($leadcount))` or `if(count($leadcount) == 0)`.